# mysql and c++ in vs 2010: sqlstatementhandle and connection error

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

**I finally solved my problem:**
I had been using a lib of mysql that was not compiled with the same settings as the VS10 project. Doing this solved my issue

**This was my issue**
I am having some trouble, and i was wondering if anyone could give me a push in the wright direction.

I am trying to connect to a local Mysql database, using c++ in VS 2010. 
On phpmyadmin i can see that an attempt to connect is made but doesn't succeed.
When building the application, i get some errors.

The first where char* errors. I solved that by changing from unicode to multi byte.

The most important error, i think, is this one:
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'sqlstatementhandle' used.

After the application crashes i get this in visual studio:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'sqlstatementhandle' is being used without being initialized.
```

In the console i get this:

```
Connecting to SQL...
Connect() - SQL_ERROR
Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Fout in het dialoogvenster
SQLSTATE: IM008
```

In the documentation i found that error code 008 refers to:

Dialog failed
SQLDriverConnect

But i don't really now how this can help? Is the driver not able to connect, or is the driver not loaded at all? As I told earlyer, i can see in phpmyadmin that there are failed attempts to connect.

my setup: visual studio 2010 and a mysql server administrated true Xampp. A 64bit windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

In connection string, Driver shows "Sql Server". Perhaps Connection String is problem. Try to change it. This site will help you.
http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p31

Comment: using the string "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase; User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;" got my from a failed attempt of connecting to an aborted connection. I'l try to work from here